# PHP & jQuery ajax Chat

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

I have created a chat application using PHP, mysql, and ajax for posting data to the server. I have tested it by spamming the chat repeatedly, and everything works for about 7 or 8 seconds until my chat will not post further. On refresh, I get a "NO DATA RECEIVED" error from google chrome. Basically I think I am overloading my site. Is there a way that I could optimize this chat? Or is it not a server-side issue at all?

This is my jQuery that is posting to my server:

```js
$(document).ready(getMessage());
//Send message
$('#send').click(function() {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    var username = $('#un').val();
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var fullname = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat/send_message.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            message: message,
            username: username,
            user_id: id,
            fullname: fullname
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#message').val('');
            getMessage();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

function getMessage() {
    $.post('chat/get_message.php', {getMessage: true}, function(message) {
        $('#chatbox').html(message);
        $('#chatbox').scrollTop($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight);
    });
}

setInterval(getMessage, 5000);
```

This is the PHP that handles the sending of the message. It just stores it in a database:

```js
<?php
//Message sending
if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo("Could not connect to the server.");
    }

    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $timesent = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `message`(`message`,`user_id`,`timesent`,`fullname`,`username`) VALUES (:message,:user_id,:timesent,:fullname,:username)");
    $query->execute(array(
        ':message' => $message,
        ':user_id' => $id,
        ':timesent' => $timesent,
        ':fullname' => $fullname,
        ':username' => $username,
    ));
} else {
    echo("Could not send message");
}
```

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><head>
    <?php
    include 'resources/head.php';
    
 if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
  Redirect::to('index.php');
    }
    ?>
<title>GoonSquad | Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        form, p, span {
            margin:0;
            padding:0; }

        input { font:12px arial; }

        a {
            color:#0000FF;
            text-decoration:none; }

        a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }

        #wrapper {
            margin:0 auto;
            padding-bottom:0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
            width: 1000px;;
            border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #chatbox {
            text-align:left;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-bottom:25px;
            padding:10px;
            background:#fff;
            height:400px;
            width:940px;
            border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
            overflow:auto; }

        #message {
            width:860px;
            border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        #submit { width: 60px; }

        .error { color: #ff0000; }

        #menu { padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px; }

        .welcome {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 150%;
        }
  
  .message {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background-color: #cccccc;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 6px;

  }

        .msgln { margin:0 0 2px 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'resources/header.php' ?>


<div id="row">
    <div id="large-9 columns" class="override" role="content">
<div id="wrapper" class="left-align">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">GoonSquad Chat</p>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox">

    </div>


    <form id="messenger" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" id="message" class="left" autocomplete="off" size="63" maxlength="2000">
        <input type="submit" id="send" class="button tiny"  value="Send" >
        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $user->data()->id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="name" value="<?php echo $user->data()->fullname?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="un" value="<?php echo $user->data()->username?>"
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already have getMessage on a timer, so don't call it in the success method of sendMessage. That's overkill.

Comment: I'd optimize it by using something other than PHP/JS and a request/response model... but props for trying it and I'm not here to shoot it down.  Are you using something like Firebug?  One thing that comes to mind is maybe a limiter on the number of requests you'll let queue up.  The browser can only do so many at once.  Either a throttle or abort method to kill queued requests when newer ones are pushed on.

Comment: @ficuscr well here is my dilemma. I'm stuck using godaddy shared hosting, so I am pretty much limited to PHP. Is there something else I could use?

Comment: I'd look at something like [Openfire/Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/) personally.  Or if you really want to code it yourself maybe learn nodeJS.  If you've got a specific issue with your current solution maybe rephrase the question a little.